# How to set up cloudkarafka brokers for the confluent rabbitmq source connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using kafka connector docker image confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0-beta1 from confluent.

I would like to set up RabbitMQ source connector the way that is described in this article:

https://rmoff.net/2020/01/08/streaming-messages-from-rabbitmq-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect/,

but instead of using local kafka broker, I would like to use the brokers that I have set up into account of  https://www.cloudkarafka.com/

Within the docker-compose.yml, I have managed to establish the connection from the connector container to the cloudkarafka brokers with the following set up:

```
kafka-connect-01:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0-beta1
    container_name: kafka-connect-01
    hostname: kafka-connect-01
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_CUB_KAFKA_TIMEOUT: 300
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "my-cloudkafka-brokers:9094"
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SASL_SSL"
      CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: "SCRAM-SHA-256"
      CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="username" password="hidden";'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 'kafka-connect-01'
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: username-c-cluster
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: username-c-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: username-c-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: username-c-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      #CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
      #CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: 'DEBUG'
      #CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=DEBUG,org.reflections=ERROR,org.eclipse.jetty.server=DEBUG'
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/,/data/connect-jars'
```

The connectivity issue:

```
[source-rabbitmq-00|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-source-rabbitmq-00-0] Connection with cloudkafka-broker disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector:607)
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:119)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:385)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:651)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:572)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:330)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

occurs with from the RabbitMQ source connector when is trying to publish the message to the CloudKafka brokers (the  DNS of the brokers were on purpose hidden).
I got the same problem, when I was using the following RabbitMQ connector configurations:

Configuration 1:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-rabbitmq-01/config \
    -d '{
        "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
        "kafka.topic" : "username-myrabbitsinktopic",
        "rabbitmq.queue" : "test-queue-01",
        "rabbitmq.username": "user",
        "rabbitmq.password": "pw",
        "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq",
        "rabbitmq.port": "5672",
        "rabbitmq.virtual.host": "/",
        "confluent.license":"",
        "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers":"cloudkafka-brokers:9094",
    "confluent.topic.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"username\" password=\"userpassword\";",
        "confluent.topic.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
        "confluent.topic.sasl.mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "offset.flush.timeout.ms":1200000000
 }'
```

Configuration 2

```
curl -i -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-rabbitmq-00/config \
    -d '{
        "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
        "kafka.topic" : "username-myrabbitmqsourcetopic",
        "rabbitmq.queue" : "test-queue-01",
        "rabbitmq.username": "user",
        "rabbitmq.password": "pw",
        "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq",
        "rabbitmq.port": "5672",
        "rabbitmq.virtual.host": "/",
        "bootstrap.servers":"cloudkafkabroker:9094",
    "sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"username\" password=\"password\";",
        "security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
        "sasl.mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "offset.flush.timeout.ms":1200000000
 }'
```

Please advice how to configure this rabbitmq connector to use the brokers provided by cloudkafka.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succeeded to connect RabbitMQ to CloudKafka by using the following configurations:

a) For the kafka connector

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
    "rabbitmq.port": "5672",
    "rabbitmq.password": "passwd",
    "rabbitmq.queue": "test-queue-01",
    "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq",
    "name": "source-rabbitmq-01",
    "kafka.topic": "c0b9uv0s-mytopic",
    "rabbitmq.username": "user",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "rabbitmq.virtual.host": "/"
}
```

b) In the docker compose

```
version: '3'
services:

  kafka-connect-01:
    image: connect-rabbitmq:latest
    container_name: kafka-connect
    hostname: kafka-connect
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_CUB_KAFKA_TIMEOUT: 300
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "cloudkarfkanode:9094"
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SASL_SSL"
      CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: "SCRAM-SHA-256"
      CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"user\" password=\"password\";"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 'kafka-connect'
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: user-w-cluster
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: user-w-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: user-w-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: user-w-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: 'INFO'
      #CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=DEBUG,org.reflections=ERROR'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=INFO,org.reflections=ERROR,org.eclipse.jetty.server=INFO'      
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/,/data/connect-jars'
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "cloudkafkanode:9094"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SASL_SSL"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM: "SCRAM-SHA-256"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"user\" password=\"password\";"


    command: 
      # In the command section, $ are replaced with $$ to avoid the error 'Invalid interpolation format for "command" option'
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-rabbitmq:1.1.1

        #
        echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
        #
        sleep infinity

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: user
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: password
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'
```

The configurations that fixed the mentioned errors are:

```
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "cloudkafkanode:9094"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SASL_SSL"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM: "SCRAM-SHA-256"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"user\" password=\"password\";"
```

I hope this will help others to fix same issue.